# Jquery Button with asp.net button . Jquery not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a two buttons in asp.net web form. One button event is handled by asp.net onclick event. I have another button whose click event is handled by jquery. If i click the jquery button it first it works fine.But if i click the asp.net button and then jquery button . The jquery event does not fire.

Any suggestion?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            return false;
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                $("#<%=btnSubmitcommunication.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                    alert('hi');
                    return false;
                  });
            });

        });
        function HeaderClick_Roles(checkBox) {
            var i;
            if (checkBox.checked) {
                for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
                    if ((document.forms[0].elements[i].type == 'checkbox') &&
                            (document.forms[0].elements[i].name.indexOf('chkBxSelect') > -1)) {
                        document.forms[0].elements[i].checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
                    if ((document.forms[0].elements[i].type == 'checkbox') &&
                            (document.forms[0].elements[i].name.indexOf('chkBxSelect') > -1)) {
                        document.forms[0].elements[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        function Check_Click(objRef) {
            //Get the Row based on checkbox
            var row = objRef.parentNode.parentNode;

            //Get the reference of GridView
            var GridView = row.parentNode;

            //Get all input elements in Gridview
            var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

            for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
                //The First element is the Header Checkbox
                var headerCheckBox = inputList[0];

                //Based on all or none checkboxes
                //are checked check/uncheck Header Checkbox
                var checked = true;
                if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i] != headerCheckBox) {
                    if (!inputList[i].checked) {
                        checked = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            headerCheckBox.checked = checked;

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1"> View1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">View2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">view3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr style="height: 34px;">
                            <td style="width: 150px; text-align: left;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblfilteredbystatement" runat="server" Text="Filtered By Statement Type" />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatement" runat="server" CssClass="ddlList" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                            </td>enter code here
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="height: 34px;">
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFIlteredDepartment" runat="server" Text="Filtered By Department" />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" CssClass="ddlList" />
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFilteredByDivision" runat="server" Text="Filtered By Division" />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivision" runat="server" CssClass="ddlList" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="ButtonSmall" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdCommunication" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Visible="True" CssClass="gridview">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridviewheader" />
                        <RowStyle CssClass="gridviewrows" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridviewalternatingrows" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Staff ID" Visible="true">
                                <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStaffd" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Staff Name <br />(Eligible Group)"
                                Visible="true">
                                <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEligibleGroup" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Annual Salary <br/>(Prior Year)"
                                Visible="true">
                                <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAnnualSalary" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Communicated?" Visible="true">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxSelect" runat="server" Visible="true" Checked="true" onClick="javascript:Check_Click(this);" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxHeader" runat="server" Text="Communicated?" onClick="javascript:HeaderClick_Roles(this);" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitcommunication" runat="server" Text="Communicate" CssClass="buttonSubmit" Visible="true" ClientIDMode="Static" />

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>
                HR BP View
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>
                Submitted Records
            </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: And where is the code??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar sorry forgot to post code

Comment: If i click on btnSubmitcommunication it works fine but if click on btnSearch first then my jqery stops firing

Comment: What code gets called on asp.net button click

Comment: Data is binded to datagrid it shows up

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$("#<%=btnSubmitcommunication.ClientID %>").click(function ()...
```

Do this:

```
$(".buttonSubmit").click(function ()...
```

*Reason*: You are using updatepanel, which means the content will be loaded thru ajax and hence the binding done earlier in the page will no longer be available. Easiest way is to use a *unique* class and then use that to bind your event.

Better still, use delegation on your wrapper:

```
$('div.tabs-1').on("click", function(e) {
    var $elem = $(e.target);
    if ($elem.hasClass('buttonSubmit')) {
        ... // your click code here
    }
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Jquery will not work with ASP.net Update panel. Since you're using Jquery I hope you wont require any Update panels. I suggest , fetch data using Web methods in JSOn format and Parse it and use it your form. You have a workaround here if you wish so.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601683/Working-with-jQuery-within-the-ASP-NET-UpdatePanel